# OneToMany relationship is not updating instead inserting

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Suppose there is a User table, and a education table.

> User table contains: userId, name, age.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "userId")
    private Collection<Educationdetail> educationdetailCollection;
```

> Education table contains: educationId, userId, stream,
>   degree(stream,degree combined unique)

```
@JoinColumn(name = "userId", referencedColumnName = "userid")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Users userId;
```

(User to education = one to many relationship.)

Now first time I added a user.
Then I added education details of the same user.

When I am going to **update** a user education details its showing that " **The given object has a null identifier**".

When I am going to **merge** showing unique constraint violation.

```
@Override
    public int saveOrUpdateProblem(Educationdetail educationdetail) {
        try{
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(educationdetail);
        return 1;
        }catch(Exception ex){
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(educationdetail);
        return 0;
        }   
    }
```

Please tell what is the mistake I am doing.
During debugging I can see the collection of education but while updating the details the education object having no identifier.
Thanks.

Comment: Post the code where you do the update.

Comment: Did you use sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(educationdetail); at first?

Comment: yes @Justas. Can you tell how should i get the id of the object for which I am getting unique constraint violation(due to saving an object which has same degree and stream) error?

Comment: Please post the objects you're trying to save. Did you use flush() or transaction commit after saving/updating?

Comment: No I am using `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)` in the interface level. So automatically flush will be called and session will be closed.

Example of object trying to save:[userId---educationDetailId---standard---stream---percentage---startDate---endDate]

1) ** 2427--- 5----BE/BTECH---Electronics---43---2016-08-02---2016-08-06**

2) ** 2427--- 5----BE/BTECH---Electronics---43---2016-08-04---2016-08-07**

Look i have changed the date. First time I have saved but second time I need to update the same.

Thanks for your eager help @Justas

Comment: Do you load it before update? What stack trace do you get? Quite difficult to understand your problem flow, need more details.